# Installing ffmpg 3.4.8 on 20.04

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to install ffmpeg 3.4.8 on my wsl ubuntu 20.04 distro.
apt madision and snap only offer me 4.2.* versions.
Building from source fails with:

```
gcc is unable to create an executable file.
If gcc is a cross-compiler, use the --enable-cross-compile option.
Only do this if you know what cross compiling means.
C compiler test failed.
```

Is there a simple way to get 3.4.8 onto 20.04? Or must I downgrade to ubuntu 18?

Comment: What is your installation procudure? This could be helpful:https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu#FFmpeg

Comment: Why do you want 3.4.8? Do you just need the `ffmpeg` cli tool or the libraries too?

Comment: I'm building something on google cloud functions which ffmpge 3.4.8 preinstalled, and I need the same setup localy to rule out version differences

Comment: Do you know which compilation options you need? If not, do you know what fomats you need to support?